# Centralizing logic for $http results (AngularJS 1.x)

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I really like Angular, but I'm an uber n00b and still trying to wrap my head around the concepts.

Currently I have about ~9 or 10 controllers that have nearly identical code:

```
$scope.saveForm = function (viewModel) {
    if ($scope.id && $scope.id > 0) {
        $http.put(appConstants.baseUrl + 'v1/SiteGroupStagings/' + $scope.id, viewModel.data)
            .then(function successCallback() {
                $scope.master = angular.copy(viewModel);
                Notification.success('Success');
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                Notification.error('An error occurred while trying to save.<br /><br />' + response.statusText + '<br /><br />'+ response.data);
            });
    } else {
        $http.post(appConstants.baseUrl + 'v1/SiteGroupStagings', viewModel.data)
            .then(function successCallback() {
                $scope.master = angular.copy(viewModel);
                Notification.success('Success');
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                Notification.error('An error occurred while trying to save.<br /><br />' + response.statusText + '<br /><br />'+ response.data);
            });
    }
};
```

So code duplication is occurring in two places:

1. This entire method is duplicated in many of my controllers (only difference is the http urls)
2. Within the method, the `then` function (after the `$http.post`/`$http.put`) are exact duplicates

My question is: what is the recommended way to centralize this logic and share it across controllers?

This is just one example of code that is nearly duplicated across many of my controllers, and obviously this is going to cause major maintainability issues.

Thank you

Comment: Short answer is use a service to share data and/or methods across controllers

Answer (score 1):

The url is a string, so you can conditionally set it, and use that for your `$http` request.

```
$scope.saveForm = function (viewModel) {
  var url = 'vi/SiteGroupStagings/' + viewModel.data;

  if ($scope.id && $scope.id > 0) {
    url = 'vi/SiteGroupStagings/' + $scope.id + viewModel.data;
  }

  $http.put(appConstants.baseUrl + url)
    .then(function successCallback() {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(viewModel);
      Notification.success('Success');
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      Notification.error('An error occurred while trying to save.<br /><br />' + response.statusText + '<br /><br />'+ response.data);
    });
};
```

Another thing I've picked up recently is that if you find yourself needing to share methods across controllers, you should look into making a service or factory. You can then call it's functions in any controller you inject it into. I found this helpful: http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/

Comment: Thanks. In your example, it doesn't account for the fact that I'm calling `.put` and `.post` separately, too.  But that's solved by using the long-form `$http({ method: 'post', url: ''})...` syntax